# is there is any list of bugs available for magento ver 1.9.1, i need just a list with solutions

Tags: magento-1.9

i have just installed a site in magento 1.9.1 , i have found during the research of the blogs that there are bugs which were there in this system. is there is ready list wth solution is available. can you provide me a link to that.

Comment: Yes, the Magento bug tracker... Sign up at Magento.com

Answer (score 1):

There is not really such a List.

Sure, there are solutions out there. But you cant be sure if they make things worse instead of helping.
That is mostly the reason why they are not fixed yet, because Magento has a very strict quality assurance, which  is quite time consuming.
Sometimes they find downsides in the submited patches, which make an including not possible.

The general rule of thumb here is to only try fixing bugs, which you actually face in your normal operations. Because most of this bugs affect only a small part of users.

If you still search for a list, the bug tracker from magento itself is probably a good search.
Also there are some community forks which try to provide a version with less bugs.
One is https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts another https://github.com/firegento/magento

Comment: Fix the bugs that directly cause issues, get yourself to work and upgrade to the latest version for the rest or face major alcohol consumption and wall repair from banging your head on it due to making the fixes and then upgrading and making the fixes again, ad infinitum.